# Socket change in LSP

Tags: c++, proxy, winsock, winsock-lsp

Is it possible to change the destination socket (IP and port) of the outgoing packets using LSP (Layered Service Provider) in Windows?

For example, I want to redirect all HTTP packets to a proxy server (given IP/port). This way I can create "system-wide" proxy for Windows.

I tried to include a call to `WSPSendTo` inside the function `WSPSend` to do the redirection. These two functions take the same parameters except that `WSPSendTo` takes two more parameters (`const struct sockaddr FAR *`, and `int`).

The problem is that the traffic has not been directed to the proxy specified in the code. I verified this using wireshark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the destination of a TCP socket once it has been connected, which is why calling `WSPSendTo` (with non NULL `lpTo`) has no effect. You should look at `WSPConnect` instead.